# What MSBuild Arguments do I need to set so that I can make this work?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfvc

I have a solution that has a Web Site (not a Web Application) and I'm having trouble setting up my Visual Studio Build task.

Usually I setup my MSBuild Arguments like so

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

Then in my Copy Publish Artifact, I e

```
$(build.sourcesDirectory)/AppSolution/Website/obj/$(BuildConfiguration)/Package/PackageTmp
```

What MSBuild Arguments do I need to set so that I can make the above work?

The files do not get copied over to the obj/$BuildConfiguration)/Package/PackageTmp folder. So when I go look at the output folder, it just looks like the code files. Not the binaries
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the MSBuild argument `/p:PackageLocation=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, then publish `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` as an artifact.